# Spring data JPA : No converter found capable of converting from type

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using spring data JPA. I am trying to fetch record from `Employee` and `Room Employee Mapping` table using `Inner Join`. I want to display specific records from Employee table so I used `new map` in `JPQL` query.

If I am removing specific records from query I am getting correct joining result but when I am adding new map with specific column I am getting following error

Can any one please tell me what I am doing wrong?

**RoomEmployeeMappingRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface RoomEmployeeMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<RoomEmployeeMapping, Integer>{

    @Query("select new map ( emp.sEmpName as sEmpName, emp.sDesignation as sDesignation, "
            + "emp.bIsPaid as bIsPaid , emp.sUnpaidComment as sUnpaidComment) from Employee as emp "
            + "Inner Join RoomEmployeeMapping as roomEmpMapping ON emp.nEmpId=roomEmpMapping.nEmpId "
            + "where roomEmpMapping.nRoomAllocationId=?1 ")
    List<Employee> findByNRoomAllocationId(Integer nRoomAllocationId);
}
```

**Error Message**

```
 "message": "No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.HashMap<?, ?>] to type [com.spacestudy.model.Employee]",
```

Comment: Just like it says. You can't convert from a HashMap to an Employee. What's the `new map` part of your query for?

Answer (score 0):

You should return Employe instances like this:

```
select new com.path.to.Employee( emp.sEmpName as sEmpName, emp.sDesignation as sDesignation, "
        + "emp.bIsPaid as bIsPaid , emp.sUnpaidComment as sUnpaidComment)....
```

make sure you use the fully qualified path to the Employee class and you have a constructor that matches the attributes passed.